# Determine if all the values in a PHP array are null

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for the most performance friendly approach to check if all values in an array are null or if it at least has one element with other types.

i.e. i need a method called containsOnlyNull($array), which returns booleans according to the passed array

e.g. :

```
$a = containsOnlyNull([null,null,null,null,null]);
$b = containsOnlyNull([null,null,1,null,null]);

// $a will be true
// $b will be false
```

Comment: array_reduce or array_walk_recursive if multidimensional array

Comment: what i have tried is very similar to what i accepted as the best answer , as mentioned in the question i was looking for (potential) better approache  ' private function containsOnlyNull($array)
    {
        $filteredArray = array_filter(
            $array,
            function ($value) {
                return !is_null($value);
            }
        );

        return count($filteredArray) === 0;
    }'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
function containsOnlyNull($input)
{
    return empty(array_filter($input, function ($a) { return $a !== null;}));
}
```

Comment: PHP 7.4 and greater: `empty(array_filter($emails, fn ($item) => !is_null($item)));`

Answer (score 10):

Since your primary objective is "**most performance friendly**", then you'll want to design a script that has the capacity to "short circuit" or `break`/`return` early.  Otherwise, you will be doing unnecessary iterations after it has been determined that a non-null value exists.

Unnecessary iteration is an unfortunate side effect of all functional-style iterating techniques for this task because they can ONLY iterate the full data set -- e.g. `array_filter()`, `array_walk()`, `array_map()`, `array_reduce()`, etc.).

As boring as it may seem to some developers, a classic loop affords the ability to break early.  Can this task be accomplished with a functional-style one-liner? Yes, but it will not outperform this snippet.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2uYgo))

```
function containsOnlyNull(array $array): bool
{
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($value !== null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

echo 'a: ' . var_export(containsOnlyNull([null,null,null,null,null]), true);  // 5 iterations for true outcome
echo "\n";
echo 'b: ' . var_export(containsOnlyNull([null,null,1,null,null]), true);  // 3 iterations for false outcome
```

Output:

```
a: true
b: false
```

---

As for functional iterators which will deliver the same boolean output, here are a some examples (but I'd still use the above technique in my own project as a matter of directness).  ([Multi-technique Demo](https://3v4l.org/SJNnY))

1. ```
   (bool) array_reduce(
       $payload,
       function ($acc, $value) {
           return $acc && $value === null;
       },
       true
   )
   ```
2. ```
   !array_filter(
       $payload,
       function ($value) {
           return $value !== null;
       }
   )
   ```
3. and most concisely:

   ```
   $payload === array_filter($payload, 'is_null')
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `array_filter` function of php as

```
function containsOnlyNull($args){
    return count(array_filter($args,function($v){return $v !== null;})) === 0;
}

$a = containsOnlyNull([null,null,null,null,null]);
$b = containsOnlyNull([null,null,1,null,null]);

echo $a."<br>";
echo $b;
```

Comment: null an 0 is not the same. But down vote is not mine ^)

Comment: I think there's no need of `callback` too @splash58

Comment: And more return (count($result) === 0 ?

Comment: @splash58 Can't get you?

Comment: Thanks @Uchiha, i have almost the same approach in mind. closer to the next suggested answer :)

Comment: It looks great, but unfortunately its conciders **zeros** and **empty strings** (i.e. '0', '') as **null** too. and in this case i need to specifically target the null values

Comment: @Ali and what about this. Simple one-liner

Comment: yeap, this is the one :), same as what @Mantas suggested, well except usage of empty() and checking the count :)

Comment: That's it the difference

Answer (score 3):

I like using [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php). This method counts the non-null items, and if larger than 0, returns false. Otherwise, it returns true.

```
function containsOnlyNull($arr) {
    return array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $item) {
        return $carry += (is_null($item) ? 0 : 1);
    }, 0) > 0 ? false : true;
}
```

**Demo:** [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/tkmZm5)

Comment: Why not reduce the array directly to a boolean?

`array_reduce($payload, function (bool $acc, $value) {
    return !$acc ? $acc : $value === null;
}, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array directly to a boolean:

```php
array_reduce($payload, function (bool $acc, $value) {
    return !$acc ? $acc : $value === null;
}, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

If your array is typed as `array<object|array|null>` (excluding falsy scalars like `0`, `false`, `''` ), you can use:

`array_filter($arr) === []`

[PHP: array_filter - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

> If no callback is supplied, all empty entries of array will be
> removed. See empty() for how PHP defines empty in this case.

So if you have only NULLs in your array, you end up with an empty array `[]`

Comment: And what if i have [null,0]?